# Statics - Volume of a Revolution

Tags: statics

The given problem asks for the Volume of the given figure below[image: The Problem]

You have a plane figure that somewhat forms a Two-circular base Paraboloid with radii 20 and 12 cms respectively, and an altitude of 16 cm when revolved about the y-axis. According to the book, the answer is 15,388 cubic centimeters and my answer on my first attempt was 4352pi cubic centimeters. I would like to know if this is an author's mistake or mine.

I used **Pappus-Guldinus Theorem  II - The Solid of Revolution** to compute manually and used the formula of a two-circular base Paraboloid to verify the answer. But I still ended up getting 4352pi cu cm.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: I got the same answer as you. It appears the book is wrong.

First, we need to solve the parabola, assuming the vertex is at the origin: $$f(x)=y=a(x-h)^2 +k$$
with $h=k=0$: 
$$f(20)=y+16=a(20)^2$$
$$f(12)=y=a(12)^2$$
$f(20) - f(12)$ would give:
$$a(400)-a(144)=y+16-y$$
$$a(256)=16$$
$$a=\frac{16}{256}=\frac{1}{16}$$
therefore $y=\frac{1}{16}x^2$ is the equation driving the parabola.

Now for the centroid of the composite shape. After careful analysis of the image from the problem and our parabolic equation we see that the shape is the area inside a parabola defined by our formula above and bounded by the $y$ axis and between the lines $y=9$ and $y=25$. We also know that the centroid of a composite shape about the $y$ axis ($\bar{X}$) is:

$$\bar{X}=\frac{\sum\bar{x}A}{\sum{A}}$$ 
where $\bar{x}$ is the centroid about the $y$ axis of the component shape and $A$ is the area of the component shape.

Using the following to find the centroid of a semi-parabolic area:

[image: Centroid of a Parabola]

and using $y=\frac{1}{16}x^2$ to solve for $y$ (or $h$) we get:

$$\bar{X}=\frac{\left(\frac{3(a_1)}{8}\right)\left(\frac{2(a_1)(h_1)}{3}\right)-\left(\frac{3(a_2)}{8}\right)\left(\frac{2(a_2)(h_2)}{3}\right)}{\left(\frac{2(a_1)(h_1)}{3}\right)-\left(\frac{2(a_2)(h_2)}{3}\right)}$$

$$\bar{X}=\frac{\left(\frac{3(20)}{8}\right)\left(\frac{2(20)(25)}{3}\right)-\left(\frac{3(12)}{8}\right)\left(\frac{2(12)(9)}{3}\right)}{\left(\frac{2(20)(25)}{3}\right)-\left(\frac{2(12)(9)}{3}\right)}$$

$$\bar{X}=\frac{\left(7.5\right)\left(333.333\right)-\left(4.5\right)\left(72\right)}{\left(333.333\right)-\left(72\right)}$$

$$\bar{X}=8.326$$

Finally, we know that the volume of an area swept around an axis is equivalent to the volume of that same area extruded along a length equal to the circumfrence of the circle scribed by the centroid as it rotates about said axis.

The area to be swept is $333.333-72 = 261.333$, and the circumference of the circle scribed by the centroid rotated about the y axis is $2\pi(8.326)\approx52.313$, giving a volume of $13,671.3$ or $4352\pi$ $cm^3$.